# AngularJS deal with API errors on a per resolve basis

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS with `UI-Router` to make a Single Page App which calls out to a REST API for json data.

I have a `app.config` like this:

```
.state('project', {
    url: '/project/:projectId/',
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/project.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
            resolve: {
                project: function ($stateParams, APIService) {
                    return APIService.get('projects/', $stateParams.projectId);
                },
                userprofiles: function (APIService) {
                    return APIService.list('userprofiles/');
                },
            }
        },
    }
})
```

And I am handling API errors using the `app.run`:

```
.run( function ($http, $cookies, $state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        $state.get('error').error = error;
        return $state.go('error');
    });
});
```

Now, this works great and any 404s form my API can easily be haded off to an `error` state and a corresponding Controller and Template.

However, what I would like is that if a 404 is returned from the `projects` API endpoint I get this behaviour (as it is part of the url), but if an error is returned from the `userprofiles` API endpoint I can return, say and empty object, and handle that error in the controller. This 404 could be considered non-critical where the `'projects` 404 would be.

What would be my best approach to this? As I build this out I expect I will want to be able handle certain API errors in their respective controllers and some at the global level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the `APIService` call returns a promise:

```
userprofiles: function (APIService) {
    // return the promise
    return APIService.list('userprofiles/').then(function(data){
        return data;
    },function(){ // and error occurred
        return {}; // return empty object on error.
    });
}
```

So long as you don't return the error to the injected property being resolved the `$stateChangeError` shouldn't occur.